# check if user can access /root directory before running command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a homework assignment that asks me to print certain things in a linux terminal with bash scripting. I have done most of them but I am stuck on the last thing I need to do...This is how my professor worded it

```
Checks to see if current user has access to /root
 -lists files in the root directory if so
 -Hint: try using 'ls'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you're having us do your homework.

Comment: `ls` is what you need, but you'll need to add some options to see permissions on that directory, so run `man ls` and take a look at the man page. If you don't know how to read a man page, Google it. This is a skill you will want to have sooner rather than later.

Comment: Is it OK to exit with an error message if the `/root` directory can not be accessed? or is it supposed to print nothing if `/root` is inaccessible?

Answer (score 0):

### Conditional Expressions and Symbolic Permissions

The simplest solution is to use a [Bash conditional expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) to check directory read permissions. For example:

```
[[ -r /root ]] && ls /root
```

If you'd rather inspect the permissions visually, you can use *ls* to list the directory (rather than its contents) with the `-d` flag. For example:

```
$ ls -lad /root
drwxr-x---  6 root  wheel  204 Oct 25 04:45 /root
```

You can then parse the permissions using [symbolic notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Symbolic_notation) to see if the current user would have access to its contents, but doing it that way just seems like the long way around when you can just use a conditional or handle the exit status of *ls* directly:

```
ls /root || echo "Grade: 'F' for effort." > /dev/stderr
```